# Change to Django's User Model - Migration issues

Tags: python, django, migration

I have used my own user model till now and suddenly i realized that django's user model offers me exactly the things that i would have to create on my own... why not to take django's user model..

now i changed the user model and made it inherit from django user model by adding:

```
class User(User)..
```

and tried to migrate the db with these steps:

```
1. python manage.py schemamigration home --auto
-- it asked me to give some default values for these two columns I mean down here
2. python manage.py migrate home
3. error
```

3.*error* says that `user_ptr_id` exists double and thats why couldnot create the unique index `user_pkey`.

what can i do now so that i can migrate?

Comment: django user Model already exists.  Normally, to extend the user model you create a new model with a `ForeignKey` referencing django's built in `User`.  If you need to migrate your data from your current user to djangos, you might need to have a script that maps your current `User` model to import the data and create entries in django's `User`.  What is the structure of your current User model? Also there might be some sort of conflict from having `User` subclass `User`.

Comment: @dm03514, i extended it by doing ``class User(User)``. this is same as if do it by defining foreign key.

Comment: try to change your model name to MyUser